# In CV, mentioning of a report that summarizes the postdoc research without publications?

Tags: publications, postdocs, cv, preprint

During a one year of postdoc of mine in pure mathematics, I didn't publish anything. I definitely did a research report and wrote down the main questions (in the form of conjectures) we were after and some ideas on how they could be solved. I'm now doing a new postdoc in an applied area as my next postdoc, and I was wondering whether it's okay/encouraged/discouraged/harmful to mention that research report in my list of publications/pre-prints. Clearly, it's just an expository report without proving any new results, which will never be published or even put on arXiv, but it does reflect the fact that I was not idle during my postdoc.

What do you think?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't sound to me like it should go on the CV. I'd say that if you're applying for jobs you'll probably get to recycle some of that material for your research statement, but it seems weird to put that piece on your CV.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't list it under "Publications" as it would detract from actually-published papers, and might even look desperate.

Like @shane, I probably wouldn't put it on the CV at all but possibly you could have a section for technical reports and other manuscripts?

Ideally you'd find time to augment it (with partial proofs, heuristics, or other stuff you've done) to form something that could be published.  (In some fields, conjectures with simulation results can form a nice paper.)